# join resource parameter string with variables - CFN

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have been trying to use different functions like sub & join to concatenate the default value of the parameter resource to variables (other input parameters).

An example is:

```
"RuleQuery": {
       "Description" : "rule query",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "SELECT parse_time(\"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss 
                     z\", timestamp(), \"Australia/Sydney\") AS 
                     timestamp, * FROM  {\"Ref\": \"TopicFilter\"} 
                     WHERE CustomerId={\"Ref\": \"CustomerID\"}" 
  }, 

  "TopicFilter": {
       "Description" : "topic filter",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "001"         
  },
  "CustomerID": {
       "Description" : "condition",
        "Type" : "String",
        "Default" : "0001"         
  },
```

Every time I get an error that the default value should remain a string. Was wondering if it is possible to achieve this at all?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't allow you to pass multi-lined strings. So, you are getting the error.

Updating your template to below style, should ideally resolve your issue.

```
"RuleQuery": {
   "Description" : "rule query",
    "Type" : "String",
    "Default" : "SELECT parse_time(\"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z\", timestamp(), \"Australia/Sydney\") AS timestamp, * FROM  {\"Ref\": \"TopicFilter\"} WHERE CustomerId={\"Ref\": \"CustomerID\"}" 
}
```